# How to Trigger End of Conversation in Botframework V4?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to get the condition `(turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation)` triggered in `OnTurnAsync` method so that I can perform some cleanup/summary for chat etc. How can I achieve that?

I've tried `CancelAllDialogsAsync()` and `EndDialogsAsync()` but both aren't going to end the chat. FYI, I'm using bot-emulator 4.2.1 and do not have other channel to test.

When `CancelAllDialogsAsync()` is called, my conversation will go back to the very first dialog (which is list of suggestion). While `EndDialogsAsync("End",cancellationToken)` just stop the conversation but did not trigger the EndOfConversation Activity type.

Comment: See if this helps you ... https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1808

Comment: thanks. Was thinking if I should just create a custom activity handler. This post reinforce the new direction to look into instead of blindly hitting on the subject.

Comment: @Taken did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from the Teams client - Teams doesn't use endOfConversation at all, and all messages between a user and your bot are forever included in the same conversation thread.

If you're using some variant of Direct-Line (e.g. botframework-webchat, or the C# Direct-Line SDK) then you can rig up a button or other element to send an "endOfConversation" activity